# How to get number of digits divisible by 5

Tags: c#

I want to find the total number of digits divisible by 5 between 1 - 100, in C# windows form, how to proceed from here?

```
int sum;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] intarray = new int[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        intarray[i] = i + 1;
    }

    foreach (int a in intarray)
    {
        if (a / 5 == 0)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `int result = 100/5;`?

Comment: total number of digits exactly divisible by 5

Comment: please mention your scenario clearly and ask specific question. And also you don't need an array to store values from 1 to 100.

Comment: Well, `100/5` will tell you how many numbers are divisible by 5 in the range `[0;100]` and it's the same for `[1;100]`

Comment: 5 is divisible by 5 and `5 / 5 == 1`. Rather use modulo operator. `5 % 5 == 0`

Comment: If i don't need an array, can u pls tell me shorter way to store values 1-100 ?

Comment: As @Cid mentionned, not only is this code poorly "designed" (you are iterating on an array instead of a counter which in your case is litterally equal to "wtf am i doing lol"), but you also need to review the basics of Maths. What if it's 100 ? `100/5 != 0` your `if` won't work. You WANT to use a modulo.

Comment: Thank you all guys, I used a % 5 == 0,  added an int count = 0; I still have some questions if u could ans them ??

Comment: 2nd class on C# guys, sry, too much of a newbie

Comment: There is a simple algorithm that allow to count numbers divisible by __x__ in range __a-b__: `(b+x)/x-(a+x-1)/x`

Comment: I can't help but think that you either are a student or just new to code in general, both ways you WANT to take a look at some beginers tutorials, not like there is thousands of good ones on the internet so you should have no problems to find them.

Comment: Trying out other methods, you guys are the best.

Comment: @1_bug wow, It worked, thanks

Comment: You should really use paper and pen befor heading head first into coding. Nothing in the code make sense. even 10 years old scratch program are mutch more logic.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/29HGz1M    image of code given by my teacher, he said complete it as homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize a variable as 0

for e.g. `Count = 0;`

then add statement `Count++` in your if block as follows:

```
            if (a % 5 == 0)
            {
                  Count++;
            }
```

Comment: `5 / 5` is 1 not 0.

Comment: do we use % sign as divide in C# ? Isn't / real divide sign?

Comment: `%` is the [modulo operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator). It's a basic math operator.

Answer (score 4):

Note than `a / 5 == 0` is wrong. For example 10 is divisible by 2, the result is 10/5 = 2, not equal to 0.

```
if (a % 5 == 0)
{
    //then a is divisible by 5. print or store it
}
```

The modulus operator, also known as Remainder, returns the remainder of the integer division.

Therefore, the full answer:

```
int nInRange = 0;
foreach (int a in intarray)
    if (a % 5 == 0)
        nInRange++;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetIntsDivisible(int start, int finish, int divisor)
{
    for (var i = start; i <= finish; i++)
        if (i % divisor == 0)
            yield return i;
}
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", GetIntsDivisible(1, 100, 5)));
}
```

or if you don't want to yield

```
public static List<int> GetIntsDivisible(int start, int finish, int divisor)
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    for (var i = start; i <= finish; i++)
        if (i % divisor == 0)
            result.Add(i);
    return result;
}
```

**Output**

```
5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100
```

[**Full demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jvTdOM)

Comment: I never understood how to use `yield`. Does, in that case and since the function is typed `IEnumerable<int>`, each `yield return i;` will act *like* `.Add(i);` ?

Comment: @Cid yes basically, when it gets enumerated over it will yield each element , or when you ToList();

Comment: What is the advantage using `yield` over returning a `List<T>` ?

Comment: @Cid none really, its just a different way of doing it, it just yields while you are enumerating over it. you could also just as easily create a list and return that, in some situations yield is more elegant

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, it became more clear. By the way, I suggest you to edit your post and to replace `if (i % 5 == 0)` by `if (i % divisor == 0)` since it's the purpose of the argument.

Comment: I am using C# in windows form, can u pls give me the code for that ?

Comment: @LostCause, lt is winforms or any framework, however i have updated my answer without yield

Comment: @TheGeneral There is a difference between `yield` and returning a `ToList()`. the `ToList` will perform the whole statement in 1 go while the `Yeild` will become much more useful when using parallelism so it can run in parallel each items and subsequent pipe query before having to complete each pipe 100%. I admit that 99% of my use case i would not care if it did a `ToList()` or a `yield`

Answer (score 1):

Since question is a bit vague in exact requirement, I will write the basic logic that can find the numbers exactly divisible by other number.

There is something called modulus (%) operator. It gives you the remainder of division.e.g. 11%5 will be 1, 13%5 will be 3, whereas 15%5 will be 0

so logic goes like,

```
for(int i=0;i<=100;i++) 
{
     if((i%5)==0)
     {
        \\this is ur number
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every one has address your question but no one talk about this weird attempt.
I really think you should take 5 minute and read your code because you are just running everywhere.

You should take  the pen and paper before going head first into coding.
Here is a simple reading of your code so you understand what you were doing.

Line 1:

```
int[] intarray = new int[100];
```

So you start win an array, I guess it's for the result, right ? You will not be storing the number from 1 to 100 for no reason?

Line 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
```

Now we count from 0 to 98, I though it was form 1 to 100 .. Yes 98 as you are using `<` instead of `<=`

Line 3:

```
intarray[i] = i + 1;
```

Why ? 3rd line and you are already lost! You are filling the array with number you just iterate. It's like filling a bottle with water, then use it to fill an other bottle because you needed water.
If you iterate from 1 to 100 you could have check if it was divisible.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
```

Line 4:

```
foreach (int a in intarray)
```

Again ? We are back counting from 1 to 100..

Line 5:

```
if (a / 5 == 0)
```

If this is suppose to tell you if it divisible thats wrong. The correct math operator is the Modulo. The division symbole won't give you the result you expect.
`{1,2,3,4}` will give you True. Anything else will be false.

Comment: sry, seems my teacher did this wrong, trying to understand this code myself.  What is the shortest/easiest way to find the answer, can u pls tell me ?

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)   , why do I have to write int i=1 instead of int i = 0  ?  Is it the starting point ?

Comment: Yes it is! `for (var i = StartingPoint; i <= FinishPoint; i++)`

Comment: well thats only the 2nd line of code from the general answer.. Everything is already here.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            if ((i % 5) == 0)
            {
                count++;
                textBox1.Text = count.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Alternatively,

int num = (100 + 5) / 5 - (1 + 5 - 1) / 5;
//Show result here

Comment: Read again the Line 2 comment from my answer! `for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)` is from 0 to 98...

Comment: sry, my 1st day at this forum and second day at c# class, I'm everywhere